# Updating indexes in database with Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: database, symfony, orm, indexing, doctrine

I'm trying to add indexes to my database using the annotation method in my User Entity class, however when I update the meta data and run an update from the command line and then go to phpMyAdmin there are no indexes for the relevant table. I have a users table with a role_id foreign key and want to add this as an index using the meta data below:

```
namespace XXX\XXXBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* User
*
* @Table(name="user",indexes={@index(name="role_id", columns={"role_id"})})
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/

class User {

}
```

Also, can someone please explain what the Index name refers to? Can this be set to anything? I assume the columns= is the field names I want to index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Index-Annotion is just on the wrong place. It has to be a annotion of the class and not of a property.

See [Doctrine 2 Docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-index)

Comment: To the entity. I've tried that method but I get an error. I'll try it again now and tell you the error message...

Comment: [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                                         
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Table" in class Cdr\WebsiteBundle\Entity\User was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement  
   for this annotation?

Comment: I've updated my question to show what the code is now. I think the problem is because it doesn't have ORM before Table. I've tried adding this and it still doesn't work?!

Comment: and your @Index needs the prefix too

Comment: and with `@ORM\Table(name="user",indexes={@ORM\Index(name="role_id", columns={"role_id"})})`?

Comment: I still get an error message when using:
* @ORM\Table(name="user",indexes={@ORM\index(name="role_id", columns={"role_id"})})

Comment: Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                                         
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\index" in class Cdr\WebsiteBundle\Entity\User does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

Comment: Should index be an uppercase I?

Comment: np, thats why we are here :-)